# master should be made non editable when there is any child associated to it

Tags: validation, master-detail

i have a situation where I need to throw an error when any use tries to edit the master record.  It has one or more child records associated with it.

- i came up with something, like i had a roll-up summary for the master
  record which gives the count of the associated child records.
- now I want to put a validation rule on the Master object using the
  Roll up summary field.
- I am stuck with the validation rule part.

is it feasible this way, or a trigger is required ?

Answer (score 1):

Both are viable options. for example

- for validation rule

  ```
  myRollupField__c > 0
  ```
- for trigger

  ```
  trigger myTrigger (before update){

      for (SObject obj : Trigger.new){

          if (obj.get('myRollupField__c') > 0){
              obj.addError('bleh');
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

about the validation you provided:
in that case, when ever  you try to add a child record the error throws up.
the error needs to pop up only when you try to edit or change the master record.

i got it resolved

`AND(myRollupField__c > 0,ISCHANGED(the field you want not get edited in the masterobject)`)

Comment: sorry if my question wasnt clear enough.